# jQuery AJAX file upload response text

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm making a jQuery/AJAX file uploader.  The response text I received is the browser's source code instead of the JSON string.

For example:

```
#image.php
print(json_encode(array(true, "Images were uploaded"));

#image.js
function uploadImages(){
  form = new FormData($(this).closest("form")[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php?action=sFi&json=nei",
    type: "post",
    xhr: function(){return($.ajaxSettings.xhr())},
    data: form,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

    success: function(json){
        //response = $.parseJSON(json);
        //alert(response);
        console.log(json);
    },

    error: function(){
        alert("ERROR");
    }
  });
}
```

In the console log, there will be

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>text</title>
 //Other html stuff
</head>
<body>
//Other html stuff
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of: true, "Images were uploaded".  Does anyone know why the json string printed from the php file doesn't get returned?

Comment: have you reviewed the body of the HTML returned?  usually when this happens, the body of the HTML contains error info.

Comment: yup. theres no error statements